# Boot time ssh not working (wheezy raspbian 2012-09-18)?

Tags: raspbian, boot, ssh, raspbian-wheezy

I have just installed the 2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian onto SD and plugged it into my pi. According to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/starting-ssh-automatically-at-boot-time), SSH should be enabled by default. I can see the pi on the network (it responds to ping) and if I do nmap:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.0.12
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-10-24 20:29 BST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.12
Host is up (0.00063s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 1 (protocol 2.0)
Service Info: OS: Linux
```

but when I try to ssh:

```
ssh -p 22 pi@192.168.0.12
```

I get

```
Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

I haven't got a suitable monitor so it's pretty hard to diagnose the problem. I checked an the symlinks to /etc/init.d/ssh are already in the runlevel directories as /etc/rc$i.d/S02ssh for i={1..5} (as per [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1706/3012)). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the host key files are missing or corrupt. To correct it try this.

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

ref: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=15814

Comment: Hmm, but how can I run this without shell access? I'll check `/var/log/regen_ssh_keys.log` when I get home

Comment: Can you connect a tv?

Comment: With a bit of hassle yes ... I was hoping I'd just be able to ssh straight into it as it's supposed to be enabled by default.

Comment: You could try reimaging the card and reinstalling. This seems to be a fairly rare occurance.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. It was a fresh image though (although I was overwriting a previous squeeze image), so that seems a bit odd. Unless it's something on the client side (ubuntu)??

Comment: Solved: I redid the image, then I followed this answer http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1706/3012 again, waited a while, and then managed to connect. Not sure what went wrong the first time around!